# weird error in php / mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I work on multipe search.
I have a variable that will automatically fill in the fields 
**the problem when I pass the query to paramettre function mysql to execute it does not support the req
and when I pass the same req directly it worked**
eg

ex :

```
$req="SELECT * FROM tableEx WHERE";
if(!empty($keyword)) $req .=" keyword like '$keyword'";
..................................................
the result of $req="SELECT * FROM ExTable WHERE keyword like 'better' AND..... ";
1.$result=query("SELECT * FROM ExTable WHERE keyword like 'better' AND.....");//work better

2.$result=query($req); // dont working
```

Comment: Try print your sql statement before `$result=query($req)` and you should see some diffrences that may cause the problem

Comment: And try hexdumping the data - its possible you have character set issues.

Comment: SELECT numAnn,typeAnn,accesAnn,departementAnn,dateRpdAnn,heureRpdAnn,intutileAnn FROM depot_annonce WHERE (intutileAnn regexp 'préparation' OR descAnn regexp 'préparation') OR (intutileAnn regexp 'exemple' OR descAnn regexp 'exemple') AND (typeAnn LIKE 'Public') AND (accesAnn=1) LIMIT 0,6
it s working in php-myadmin . 
and when i  passe this query to dinamic variable dont working ??

Comment: i doubt in variable $req

Answer (score 2):

Try to print $req before to execute and post the result.

Your code has a potential security hole, sanitize always the variables before to use it:

```
if(!empty($keyword)) $req .=" keyword like '" .mysql_real_escape_string($keyword)."'";
```